# Pass SSH Escape into nested SSH session

Tags: ssh

Suppose I ssh from my laptop to a server `alpha`, then from there ssh to a server `beta`.

If the connection from `alpha` to `beta` dies, is it possible to pass SSH's escape (`~.`) across the ssh connection from my laptop to `alpha`, to the ssh client connected to `beta`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `man ssh` says it all:

> -e escape_char
>                Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty (default: ‘~’).
>                The escape character is only recognized at the beginning of a
>                line.  The escape character followed by a dot (‘.’) closes the
>                connection; followed by control-Z suspends the connection; **and
>                followed by itself sends the escape character once**.  Setting the
>                character to “none” disables any escapes and makes the session
>                fully transparent.

You need to send `~~.` Alternatively you could change the escape character for every ssh hop you take with `ssh -e escape_char`.

You can also specify it as a runtime option; e.g. `-o EscapeChar=:`

Thus you may also add it to your client config file `${HOME}/.ssh/config`.